# Describe 2<x<5 in words

Tags: inequality

I saw in the textbook $2<x<5$ is described as *"x is greater than 2 but less than 5"*. Is it correct to use "and" instead of "but"?

I think describe the inequality as *"x is greater than $2$ **and** less than $5$"* is also correct, is this true? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is correct (even better, imo).

Comment: I think *and* is better than *but*, there is no contraposition, just two equal facts about $x$.

Comment: the set of numbers sitting between $2$ and $5$

Comment: "and" means two things are both true.  "but" means two things are both true but there was an emotional reason to think they might not be.  Math doesn't care about emotions.  In math, "and" and "but" mean the exact same thing--- that two things are both true.  (maybe we expected it and maybe we didn't but we don't actually care if we expected it or not)  .... tl;dr.   "Is it correct to use "and" instead of "but"?" Yes.  "is also correct, is this true? " Yes.

Comment: I think there are two attitudes.  1) the excited tour guide: "You see!  This means that $x$ is greater than $2$.  But don't get carried away!  There is still another condition! It's true that $x$ is greater than $2$ but that doesn't last forever! We also have the condition $x$ is less than $5$.  So $x$ is greater than $2$ but also $x< 5$"....   Or 2) the bored existential fact giver.  "$x$ is greater than $2$. And  $x$ is less than $7$. That's it.  I'm done. I'll be at the bar if you have any other questions".  (Honestly.... I'd use "and" myself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, Both are correct.
Because here "but" & "both" these two are working as conjunction. There is no difference whether you use "but" or "and". But if you use or then the meaning is changed, so you can use both as far as language is concerned.